# What is "ambulatory care pharmacy"?

Tags: word-meaning

> You are working as a pharmacy technician in an **ambulatory care** pharmacy. A pharmacist hands you the prescription and asks you to compound the product based on the pharmacy’s written protocol.

Could you tell me in simple English what kind of pharmacy is an ambulatory care pharmacy, please?

Comment: It  means the patients are capable of walking, and thus are not in bed in the hospital but visiting it on a so-called "outpatient" basis for treatment or physician's appointments. The typical customer at the counter will be a patient, not medical personnel.

Comment: @TRomano That's worth an answer, IMHO!

Answer (score 1):

To expand upon the existing comment:

In medical terms, an *ambulatory* patient is one who can walk.  After an accident those who are colloquially known as the *walking wounded* are more properly referred to as *ambulatory*.

Thus an [*ambulatory pharmacy*](https://www.bpsweb.org/specialties/AmbulatoryCarePharmacy.cfm) would have in stock those drugs that may be required by ambulatory patients for their treatment.  It will not necessarily stock more powerful drugs that would only be used for a bed-ridden inpatient.  For example strong sedatives or intravenous preparations.

As indicated in the linked article above, they may be found not just in hospitals but in clinics and other smaller centres.